# Find the smallest natural n with the property

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Find the smallest natural $n$ with the property that it enters any $n$ distinct numbers from the set $\{1, 2, 3,\dots , 999\}$ we can find four distinct numbers $a, b, c, d$ such that $a + 2b + 3c = d$.
I dont't have any idea to solve this porblem. Can someone give a hint for me? Thanks for attention.

Comment: Are $a, b, c, d$ taken from the set of those $n$ elements?

Comment: Hint: $n$ can not be equal to $3$, because the subset $\{1,2,999\}$ doesn't have the property in question. It can not be equal to $4$ because the subset $\{1,2,3,999\}$ doesn't have that property...so on. Use this observation to get a first lower bound for $n$.

Comment: @Dude , yes, a,b, c and d are taken from the set of these n elements.

Comment: You can rephrase the problem like:
Find largest  natural number $n$,such that there exist some $n$ element subset  of {1,2...,999} which does not contain such $a,b,c,d$ satisfying the given property.

Answer (score 1):

**1- Find a lower bound for $n$**

Hint: For which values of $x$, does the set $\{999 - x, 999 - x + 1, \dots, 999\}$ **not** satisfy the property for a simple reason ? For example, $x=10$ is impossible, because the smallest $a + 2b + 3c$ in the corresponding set would be larger than $999$.

**2- Show that the obtained lower bound, $n_0$, is the solution**

Hint: Consider $\{x_1, \dots, x_{n_0}\}$, an arbitrary subset of $n_0$ elements of $\{1, \dots, 999\}$, such that $x_1 < \dots < x_{n_0}$, and let $f: (a, b, c) \mapsto a + 2b + 3c$. It would suffice to show that there are 3 numbers $m_1, m_2, m_3 \in \{1, \dots, n_0\}$, such that $f(x_{m_1}, x_{m_2}, x_{m_3}) \in \{x_1, \dots, x_{n_0}\}$. Is it possible that there aren't such three numbers? The pigeonhole principle might be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint:}$

Take the subset $S=\{166,167,\cdots,999\}$
Then,it is easy to see S won't contain such $a,b,c,d$.

This immediately gives you $n \ge 835$ since $|S|=834$